# cuda simple application working for 32 bit not for 64 bit

Tags: cuda, windows-10, visual-studio-2015

My simple cuda helloworld application runs fine when built in 32 bit using visual studio 2015 community on windows 10. However, if I build it in 64 bit, it is not executed

> GPU: Telsa K40c
>
> ToolKit: CUDA 8
>
> Operating System: windows 10 64bit
>
> Visual Studio: community edition.

there is no error message in output console.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include<stdio.h>
__global__ void welcome() {
printf("Hello world :)");
}

int main() {
welcome << <1, 1 >> > ();
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I followed exact steps in installation guide, if it is a broken installation how deviceQuery sample will work.

Comment: Do you produce a 64-bit CUDA code in addition to 64-bit host code? That is a separate flag that controls it. More precisely `nvcc -m32` generates 32-bit device code, lack of such flag generates 64-bit device code.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and opened a bug to nvidia #1855074.

They reproduced it successfully and I'm waiting for update on it.

One thing is sure, it's on their side.

The only workaround I found was to put my card in WDDM mode via nvidia-smi, which broke my taskbar.

I recommend to wait for a fix.

Comment: how to track this bug?  has this been resolved?  I am facing a similar issue.  cudaMalloc just hangs in Win10 x64 in one of my application!

Comment: I can confirm that CUDA 9.1 with VS 2017 15.5.6 has the same issue.  I have a plugin based application where the core application loads dlls at runtime.  All these dlls use CUDA.  The dlls that work without issue use `dlib` deep learning library.  The issue is caused by a specific dll that uses `darknet` deep learning framework and it hangs when calling cudaMalloc.

Comment: Then you can reopen it. Create a dev account and file the bug with a minimal reproducer