# cudaMalloc hang when building x64 version binary

Tags: cuda

I'm using the CUDA toolkit version 8 on windows 10 with K20c.

After I installed the toolkit, I try to run a test code which just do add of two array in visual studio. However, I found if I build with x64, the code will hang on `cudamalloc`, nothing error but just hang there, but if I build it with x86 configuration, the code works and finish successfully.

I will appreciate that for any help.

Comment: This appears to be similar to [this report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42349712/cuda-simple-application-working-for-32-bit-not-for-64-bit), and I have added a note internal to the bug listed there to refer to this report also.

Comment: What happens if you _don't_ cudaMalloc(), but just launch a kernel which does nothing?

Comment: I try another sample code which just do device query. I mean there is no `cudaMalloc` invoke, and the x64 version binary finished with no error. So looks like only `cudaMalloc` will hang.